# Pulling data & Parsing LinkedIn data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, linkedin-api

I am using gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2' alongside gem 'devise' in my new rails 4 app to be able to authenticate users. I am able to do this and now I want to take the information that I am getting when they accept, and to be able to add certain parts of that to my database. I've read that the information that I'm getting is a JSON Hash. I would like to be able to take certain parts of the information and then be able to show it in a view. Here's my config/initalizers/devise.rb file where I am asking for certain access from the LinkedIn acct.

```
require 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2' 
config.omniauth :linkedin, "APP_ID", "APP_Secret", :scope => 'r_fullprofile                      r_emailaddress r_network', p  :fields => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name",  "headline", "industry", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "location", "connections"]
```

Sorry for that weird gap between 'r_fullprofile and r_emailaddresses.

Here is my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Danapp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
Signed in as <%= current_user.name %>. Not you?
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,:method => :delete %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> or
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
<%= link_to "Sign in with Linkedin",user_omniauth_authorize_path(:linkedin) %>
<% end %>

<%= yield %>

</body>


</html>
```

I am looking for ways on how to start LinkedIn integration with my rails app. Any help would be greatly appreciated and once again, thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of adding an extra layer before the user called Identity to hold information you get from omniauth strategy. With this you add additional strategies (Twitter, Github, Google...) for the same user to login.

So how does it works: the strategy's (linkedin) callback will create an identiy and load it with data from the API response.
You then Find or Create a new user based on this identity. In this step you load the identity info into the user info.

I've got this code from: https://github.com/alex-klepa/rails4-bootstrap-devise-cancan-omniauth
<strike>I'll add the original source where I got this code as soon as I find it.</strike> But here is my implementation:

#### in my controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    identity = Identity.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    user = identity.find_or_create_user(current_user)

  # if user.save
    if user.valid?
      logger.debug "User signed in:"
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      logger.debug "User not valid"
      logger.debug "#{user.errors.inspect}"
      user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
       flash.notice = msg
      end
      flash[:error] = 'User/Company not allowed.'
      # sign_in user
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  alias_method :linkedin, :all
  # alias_method :twitter, :all
end
```

#### in my models/identity.rb:

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  serialize :company
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    identity = where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |identity|
    identity.provider     = auth.provider
    identity.uid          = auth.uid
    identity.token        = auth.credentials.token
    identity.secret       = auth.credentials.secret if auth.credentials.secret
    identity.expires_at   = auth.credentials.expires_at if auth.credentials.expires_at
    identity.email        = auth.info.email if auth.info.email
    identity.image        = auth.info.image if auth.info.image
    identity.nickname     = auth.info.nickname
    identity.first_name   = auth.info.first_name
    identity.last_name    = auth.info.last_name
    # I need to refactor the line below urgently
    identity.company      = auth.extra.raw_info.threeCurrentPositions.values.map { |n| n.first.company.name if n.kind_of?(Array) }.compact
  end
  identity.save!
    if !identity.persisted?
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "Something went wrong, please try again."
    end
    identity
 end
 def find_or_create_user(current_user)
   if current_user && self.user == current_user
   logger.debug "User logged in and the identity is associated with the current user"
   # User logged in and the identity is associated with the current user
   return self.user
  elsif current_user && self.user != current_user
   logger.debug "User logged in and the identity is not associated with the current user"
   logger.debug "so lets associate the identity and update missing info"
   # User logged in and the identity is not associated with the current user
   # so lets associate the identity and update missing info
   self.user = current_user
   self.user.email       ||= self.email
   self.user.image       ||= self.image
   self.user.first_name  ||= self.first_name
   self.user.last_name   ||= self.last_name
   self.user.company     ||= self.company
   # self.user.skip_reconfirmation!
   self.user.save!
   self.save!
   return self.user
 elsif self.user.present?
   logger.debug "User not logged in and we found the identity associated with user"
   logger.debug "so let's just log them in here"
   # logger.debug "#{self.inspect}"
   # User not logged in and we found the identity associated with user
   # so let's just log them in here
   return self.user
 else
   logger.debug "No user associated with the identity so we need to create a new one"
   # logger.debug "#{self.inspect}"
   # No user associated with the identity so we need to create a new one
   user = User.where(email: self.email).first
   if user.nil?
     self.build_user(
       email: self.email,
       image: self.image,
       first_name: self.first_name,
       last_name: self.last_name,
       company: self.company
     )
     # self.user.save!(validate: false)
     self.save!
     self.user.save
   else
     self.user_id = user.id
     self.save!
     self.user.save
   end
   return self.user
 end
end
end
```

Comment: Beto, in your models/identity.rb how is that accessing the other type of social media data like you said in your introduction?

Comment: Well, in my example I'm not accessing any other social media. You could uncomment `alias_method :twitter, :all` and add a Twitter strategy to your omniauth and a user would be able to login with both. Since this code was created to accept various Strategies the `from_omniauth` method only looks for information that is common to all strategies. What you can do, as I did in `identity.company = auth.extra.raw_info.threeCurrentPositions.values.map { |n| n.first.company.name if n.kind_of?(Array) }.compact` is that I'm loading the companies that linkedin provides me. You could do something similar.